# int() argument must a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot, sensors

I have little to no skill at programming, but I need to take measurements with various sensors which are connected to my raspberry pi 3, and send them to thingspeak. I'm using this as a reference: https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/iot-based-raspberry-pi-weather-station-using-dht11-and-bmp180-sensor . The error I'm getting is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znsu3.png)

My code is identical to the one on the link, the only differences are the api key and gpio pin.

**Line 128 is** : `main()` , which is at the very end.

**Line 114 is** : `(humi, temp)= readDHT()` .

Lastly, **line 104 is** : `return (str(int(humi)), str(int(temp)))` .

Thank you.

Comment: Post all relevant code and error directly in the question as text.

Comment: I think this error is fairly self explanatory. If you try to print the values before turning them into integers, I think you would find that they are in fact none. There is likely a bug somewhere in your code that you need to find and fix before this section will work. Also please don't use images to display text. Try using a code block for your error message next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting information back from the lines:

```
humi, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, DHTpin)
return (str(int(humi)), str(int(temp)))
```

for instance, humi is not receibing any value. you should verify that the definition of DHTpin (currently is pin 22) is th same that you have connected the sensor to

Comment: Thanks Guido, I'm using GPIO 17 so I put 17, but maybe it's asking about the actual pin which would be 11.

Comment: I tried 11, then when that didn't work. I moved the pin to 22 and ran it again, then that also didn't work.

Comment: have you tried to turn on a simple led with any gpio? maybe you've got an issue with the gpios controller